# Warum ist das Theater sächlich?

Tags: article

Sind nicht normalerweise alle Nomen auf *-er* männlich?

Ist das Theater eine Ausnahme? Oder gilt hier eine andere Regel?

Comment: As a side note: I just changed the position of *nicht* in your sentence to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: Ja, zum Beispiel auch "die Oper", "die Wupper", "das Klavier"... :)

Comment: Die Wupper ist allerdings ein Eigenname und somit eh speziell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules (of thumb) to the articles are given on [this page](http://www2.hszg.de/%7Ebgriebel/artikelregel.html)

The article is *der* if the substantive with the ending -er describes a person or a machine

> Substantive mit der Endung -er, die Personen/Geräte bezeichnen, haben den Artikel der.
>
> - der Lehrer
> - der Betreuer
> - der Computer

The article is *die* if the substantive with the ending -er is derived from a verb with the ending *-ern*

> Substantive mit der Endung -er, die von Verben mit der Endung -ern (dauern) gebildet werden, haben den Artikel die.
>
> - die Dauer (dauern)
> - die Trauer (trauern)
> - die Mauer (mauern)

All other substantives with the ending -er **can** have the article *das* (I know that sounds stupid but it is the sentence on that page)

> Substantive mit der Endung -er können den Artikel das haben.
>
> - das Zimmer
> - das Theater
> - das Wetter

Comment: Notice the difference between *[die Leiter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leiter_Anfuehrer_Stoff)* and *[der Leiter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Leiter_Tritt_Stiege_Geraet)*.

Comment: The first rule isn't perfect: "die Mutter", "die Tochter". And an counter-example for the second rule is: "das Ruder (rudern)".

Comment: Another counter-example for the second rule: „das Lager“ (lagern).

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of exceptions. It's just a rule of thumb, but we all know, that German articles are *fürn A**** :D*

Comment: The first rule is too generic: "Computer" is essentially a Latin–English loanword and doesn't fit into this rule. The rule generally applies to professions and when the noun is derived from a verb. The second rule also mixes up different etymologies: "Dauer" and "Trauer" are Germanic, but "Mauer" is a Latin loanword derived from "murus" (masculine!). And the third rules again confuses Germanic words and loanwords: "Theater" is neuter because the Greek "theatron" is neuter. Better think in etymologies than word classifications.

Answer (score 13):

Verlasse dich bei deutschen Artikeln *niemals* auf Regeln! Es gibt mehr Ausnahmen als Regeln. Lerne am besten bei jedem Wort das Geschlecht gleich mit.

Wer von Kindesbeinen an Deutsch als Muttersprache lernt, lernt auch keine Regeln.

> der Teller, die Feier, das Messer.
>   der Vater, die Mutter.

Comment: +1, because so true.

Comment: Na ja, niemals ist ein bisschen übertrieben :) Alle Wörter auf -ung sind weiblich. Ich kenne keine einzige Ausnahme :)

Comment: Doch, der Klassiker @MurVotema Der Sprung ;p

Comment: Oder "Dung" :-)

Comment: Aber im Grunde genommen, ist 'ung' in beiden Wörtern keine Endung, sondern ein Teil des Stammes. Ich gebe zu, für einen Anfänger könnte das nicht unbedingt sofort ersichtlich sein.

Comment: Seit ich diese Antwort gegeben habe und das ~ung-Beispiel gelesen habe, frag ich mich, ob es Wörter gibt die auf ~heit oder ~keit enden und nicht weiblich sind. Mir fällt kein Beispiel ein. Ist das also doch eine Regel ohne Ausnahmen? Ich kann es kaum glauben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Geh [diese Liste](http://wortsuche.com/ends-with-by-length/keit/) durch ;p Aber ich glaube, es werden wohl auch nur so *Ausnahmen* wie beim -ung geben.

Comment: Tatsächlich gibt es durchaus zahlreiche einfache Regeln für das Geschlecht von Substantiven. Deine Beispiele sind urindogermanische Wörter, die notorisch schwierig zu handhaben sind, aber für große Klassen von Wörtern auf -er (Berufe, handelnde Personen, Lehnwörter...) lassen sich durchaus Regeln finden.

Comment: Lustiges Faktum: im Standarddeutschen heißt es die Butter, im bayerischen der Butter (ebenso der Radio).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast just for Fun: es gibt Wörter, die auf -heit und -keit enden und nicht weiblich sind: der Scheit, das Fahrenheit (Maßeinheit), der Bartelkeit, der Franckeit (und andere Minerale). Klar, alle diese Wörter zählen natürlich nicht wirklich ;-)

Answer (score 11):

"Theater" is Greek, and Latin and Greek words (which don't identify persons or animals) have a tendency to get the neutral gender:

> - das Theater
> - das Museum
> - das Gymnasium
> - das Fenster
> - das Konklave
> - das Partikel (physikalisch)
> - das Tabernakel
> - das Kolosseum
> - das Auto(mobil)
> - chemische Elemente auf "-ium"

Of course there are many exceptions, e.g.

> - der Dom
> - die Enklave
> - die Partikel (grammatikalisch)
> - die Akropolis
> - der Olymp
> - der Limes
> - die Odyssee, die Ilias
> - der (Omni)bus
> - die Bibliothek
> - die Porta Nigra

Comment: Hmmmm .. das Fenster doesn't come from Latin or greek, does it?! But yes, I think, I've heard something like you wrote.

Comment: From Latin "fenestra". The original German word had the meaning "Wind-Auge", which is where "window" came from ( http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=window ).

Comment: "fenenstra" is feminine, unlike "Fenster". Greek and Latin loanwords have adapted the original gender only when introduced in the Middle Ages or later, but words like "Fenster", "Mauer" and "Keller" were already introduced in antiquity.

Comment: I don't think that there is a general tendency towards neuter words in Greek and Latin. For example, the huge class of abstract nouns ending in -io (region, action, etc.) is feminine.

Answer (score 3):

Als ich einen Erklärungspost in meinem Blog über deutsche Artikel schrieb, fiel mir eine wahrscheinlich notwendige Bedingung auf.

Nur die Wörter, die aus dem Verbstamm und dem Suffix -er zusammengebildet werden, sind immer männlich.

D.h.

```
spielen -> der Spieler
zeigen -> der Zeiger
arbeiten -> der Arbeiter
```

Alle andere Wörter, die auf -er enden, muss man zusammen mit ihren Artikeln auswendig lernen. Und **das Theater** ist eins davon.

Aber vielleicht findet jemand eine Ausnahme zu meiner Hypothese :)

Answer (score 3):

Theater ist als Lehnwort ein Neutrum, weil es von griech. θέατρον (theatron) abgeleitet ist, das selbst ein Neutrum ist. Die Oper ist feminin, weil es aus dem italienischen opera in musica stammt, dort also bereits feminin ist.

Comment: Ok, dann muss man erst die Artikel der Ursprungsprache kennen und somit ist das erstmal schwer zu gebrauchen

Comment: @MurVotema Ist doof, aber ist so, wenn man es sich herleiten möchte. Ansonsten muss man es lernen.

Comment: Ja .. es ging mir hauptsächlich darum die 100%-Regeln zu finden, dh. die ohne Ausnahmen gelten und bei denen man den zugehörigen Artikel nicht auswendig lernen muss. Ich glaube, für Wörter auf -er gilt die von mir vermutete in meiner Antwort beschriebene Regel

Comment: @MurVotema Stimmt. Ich bezog mich speziell auf die Ausnahme in der Frage. Gerade bei lat. und griech. Fremdwörtern wird häufig das Geschlecht der Ursprungsprache beibehalten, siehe http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44/do-latin-loanwords-conserve-their-gender