# Geschlecht neuer zählbarer und unzählbarer Substantive

Tags: gender, neologism

Ich habe gerade über Geschlechter von Substantiven nachgedacht. Im Standarddeutschen ist Butter weiblich, aber soweit ich weiß, kommen landschaftlich alle drei Geschlechter vor. Weniger überraschend ist, wenn bei neuen Wortschöpfungen kein Konsens bezüglich des Geschlechts besteht. Als ich dann über *Nutella* nachgedacht habe, schien mir, dass *das Nutella* besser passt, weil mir *der Nutella* etwas Zählbares zu implizieren schien. Ist das nur mein persönlicher Eindruck, oder haben neue Substantive eine Tendenz, sächlich zu sein, wenn sie unzählbar sind, und männlich, wenn sie zählbar sind?

Comment: Bei Nutella könnte eine Rolle spielen, dass es ähnlich wie "Nuteller" klingt, was wiederum ein sehr starkes Pattern ist "Der Fahrer, Lehrer, Bäcker..."

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do Germans associate neologisms and borrowed nouns with a gender/linguistic feature when this is not clear from the language of origin?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/how-do-germans-associate-neologisms-and-borrowed-nouns-with-a-gender-linguistic)

Comment: also possibly a duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Comment: Danke für die Kommentare und auch für die Hinweise auf frühere Fragen hier. Diese hatte ich in Erinnerung, ich denke aber, dass die konkrete Frage, die ich habe, dort nicht beantwortet ist.

Answer (score 2):

Das Geschlecht neuer Wortschöpfungen orientiert sich, meiner Meinung nach, oft an ähnlich klingenden Namen und Konzepten.

'Nutella' hat '-a' am Ende, was im Lateinischen immer die weibliche Form war. Das schlägt sich in weiblichen Vornamen heute noch nieder, von Arabella bis Ursula.

Es stimmt, -a kann auch den Plural andeuten. '-um' Einzahl, '-a' Mehrzahl, aber ich glaube das ist für die Allgemeinheit schon zu subtil. Außerdem hat mir noch niemand einen Nutellus oder ein Nutellum serviert. Im konkreten Fall würde ich **'eine Nutella'** als korrekt betrachten.

Bei anderen Neuschöpfungen oder auch Fremdwörtern greift man gerne auf das grundlegende Konzept zurück. Das Wort 'Monsun' gibt keine Hinweise auf ein Geschlecht, weil es aus Indien kommt, aber es handelt sich um einen Wind, also ist **der** Monsun männlich.

Zählbarkeit wird jedoch nicht durch das Geschlecht kommuniziert. **Das** Öl, **die** Milch und **der** Wein sind alle 'unzählbare' Flüssigkeiten. **Das** Korn, **die** Traube und **der** Tropfen sind 'zählbar'.

Vielleicht hast du persönlich den unterschwelligen Eindruck, dass sachlich nicht-zählbar bedeutet, weil obige Deklination (-um Einzahl, -a Plural) sachlich ist, oder weil maskulin konkreter ist als ein Neutrum. Die deutsche Sprache folgt aber solchen Regeln nicht, soweit ich weiß.

Im Übrigen würde ich auch klar und eindeutig "**die** Butter" sagen, aber vielleicht gibt es da regionale Variationen.

Comment: Nur zur Vollständigkeit: in Ö. heißt es "das Nutella", ebenso wie "das Cola". Ohne Angabe von Gründen ;-)

Comment: @wolfgang als Österreicher habe ich immer 'die Nutella' gehört und gesagt. Aber anscheinend ist das unterschiedlich.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to Sams answer.

1. You have the perspectives

Singular
1st person ich
2nd person du
3rd person er, sie, es

Plural
1st person wir
2nd ihr
3rd sie

Now it's interesting that 3rd person plural is not er or es but sie. It's also the formal form to be used when addressing strangers. People you don't know (yet). I.e. you are impersonal to them. Add to that that men like to call machines or ships female names that they need to maintain but that are complicated and potentially flaky. Like having a ghost in the machine.

So:
er = known, predictable, almost reliable
sie = unknown, mostly magic ;)
es: for exaple das Kind, das Tier, das Wasser, aber der Wald, die Wolke
So:
es: even more unknown than the sie. Adults as far as I can tell used to not understand kids at all. In recent history with research and science that has changed a bit. Still me interacting with kids, I have no clue why they would act like this, other than they don't know any better. Somer adults are similar from my perspective but they become more rational and predicable with age.

So how would that apply to newly coined words?

If you go by taste. You could alliterate to it being female sweet or male bitter. Like der Zucker oder der Senf. ;) Or you could go by predictability of taste like die Wurst or der Fisch but das Schnitzel. Or you could just use the article from something you know like die Erdnuss-Butter or der Brotaufstrich or die Konfitüre or das Gemisch, das ich mir aufs Brot schmiere.

So rule? The good thing about rules is, there are so many to choose from. Pick the one you like.

The rule is the context of what you want to express. I.e. male, female, magic or whatever. Or if you are used to some type of article the use that one if it is common in an area.

Answer (score -1):

Der Eindruck könnte damit zusammenhängen, dass Menschen meist einen Namen oder eine Bezeichnung haben und somit z. B. "der Bäcker" oder "die Tanja" genannt werden. Dagegen werden Sachen nicht personalisiert und selten voneinander unterschieden, wodurch es relativ oft unpassend erscheint, ein Geschlecht zuzuordnen ("der Wasser"/"die Wasser"? oder "der Universum"/"die Universum"?).

`"Glückliche" - der`

Wir sprechen nicht von vielen glücklichen Leuten, da das Glücklichsein hier ein flüchtiger Zustand ist. Auch macht es wenig Sinn, eine Person in ihrer Stimmungslage mit anderen Personen in gleicher Stimmung zu vergleichen. Das Substantiv (Glücklicher) wird hier mit einem Geschlecht versehen (m/w, hier m).

`"Nagetier" - das`

Hier wird nicht auf ein ganz bestimmtes Individuum der Vielzahl der "Nagetiere" Bezug genommen. Wenn in einem Tier-Dokumentarfilm genannt, vertritt das gezeigte Exemplar die ganze Tiergattung, dessen zugehörige Arten bzw. Individuen größtenteils (in diesem Bezug) Pflanzenfresser sind. Falls von einem bestimmten Tier – z. B. einem Haustier – gesprochen wird, hat es wahrscheinlich einen Namen bekommen und wird danach genannt, mit Verwendung eines Geschlechts.

Fazit: Bei Dingen/Personen, die sehr unterschiedlich sein können oder bei denen Unterschiede deutlich oder wichtig sind, wird ein Geschlecht angewendet. Bei Dingen wie Wasser wird nicht wirklich unterschieden, welches Wasser es ist, weil es (alltäglich gesehen) überall "gleich ist".

Comment: Was für eine wirre Theorie.

Comment: @Ingmar … aber trotzdem nicht Grund genug, nicht freundlich auf German.SE begrüßt zu werden.

Comment: Also ist *der* Fisch oder *die* Spinne persönlicher als *das* Nagetier? Und *der* Staub wird generell unterschieden, wie auch *der* Sand, während *das* Spielzeug alltäglich gesehen überall "gleich" ist?