# Der Level vs. das Level

Tags: gender

[Wiktionary entry](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Level) about the word "Level" gives 2 possible genders for that noun, but without explaining, is there any difference between them. Google search also hasn't given me any reasonable answer*.

Is there **any** difference between der Level and das Level, so it doesn't matter which one I use, as long as I'll be consistent about it, or they are used for different types of "levels"?

<sub>* I've found a discussion on gutefrage, where the 2/3 of content were marketing links, and 90% of the rest were trying to offend previous poster</sub>

Comment: "gutefrage" - the source of all wisdom. Not. Check it out and see how many answers say "I don't know either...".

Answer (score 2):

I think there is not really a difference. Everything where "Level" is used, you can use both of them. If it is a pysichal level, the level of a character in a video game or the level as a synonym of map (also gaming context).

Everywhere you can use

> "der Level" or "das Level"

Maybe its not clear, because its not a native german word. Synonyms in german woudl be

> Niveau (also not native german), Höhe, Ausmaß

That leads me to [this post](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/10989/geschlecht-neuer-zahlbarer-und-unzahlbarer-substantive), where the gender of "new" words is discussed.

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/how-do-germans-associate-neologisms-and-borrowed-nouns-with-a-gender-linguistic ... see also the related posts there.

Comment: Your link does not provide the difference between `der Level` and `das Level`

Comment: I know. I posted it since you linked to a question that has the same topic and for which I voted close (duplicate)

Comment: ah okay ... just linked to it because it was opened some hours before

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if my use here is correct, but i use "der Level" when talking about level in relation with a character level (rpg), and "das Level" when talking about a stage in a game or when it is in relation with niveau.

> Das Level mit den vielen Pflanzen ist schwer. (talking about a game)
>
> Welchen Level hat Dein Charakter? (talking about character level)
>
> Wir bewegen uns hier auf einem völlig anderem Level. (talking about
>   niveau, 'das Level' here)

I agree to other answers stating that both are correct, as both are commonly used and nothing 'sounds wrong'. Anyway, I would always tend to use it like this, even if i would not correct others who do not. This might be a personal opinion, but since i am a native speaker and feel fine with this, maybe someone has a detailed explanation..