# Der / Die / Das Butter?

Tags: gender, dialect, colloquial, regional

Ein beliebtes Streitthema.

Der Duden definiert *Butter* als feminin. Wikipedia merkt an, dass im Norddeutschen auch der männliche Artikel verwendet wird. Woher aber kommt die Verwendung des neutralen Artikels? Und in welchen Regionen wird was verwendet?

Comment: Ich kann bestätigen, dass es im Schwabenland *auch* maskulin verwendet wird. Ich, persönlich, sage die Butter, aber z.B. die Oma eines Freundes von mir würde sagen "Gib mir mal bitte den Butter".

Comment: Jetzt wüsste ich gern, ob wirklich jemand (ernsthaft, nicht aus Spass) "das Butter" sagt.  Und wo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### [Die Butter](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Butter&submit_button=Suche&view=1)

Hier handelt es sich um ein Lehnwort aus dem griechischen *βούτυρον* oder dem lateinischen *butyrum*. Vielleicht war daher das Geschlecht des Wortes nie ganz klar. Siehe dazu auch folgende Fragen hier:

- [Do Latin loanwords conserve their gender?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44/do-latin-loanwords-conserve-their-gender)
- [For new words which are often nouns who sets the gender?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender)

In unterschiedlichen Regionen Deutschlands wurde zum Teil wie im Latein ein Neutrum gebildet, aber es gab auch das Maskulinum. Heute hat sich das Femininum durchgesetzt. Die anderen Varianten blieben aber in den Dialekten erhalten. Über die unterschiedlichen Genus schreiben die [Grimms in ihrem Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB13608):

> Die deutschen stämme, welche das wort annahmen, schwanken in genus und flexion. *ags.* butere, *gen.* buteran *f.*, *fries* butere, *gen.* butera, *engl.* butter, *nnl.* boter, *nhd.* butter, unveränderlich. *ahd.* aber kann in landstrichen, wo *mhd.* butter, *gen.* butteren, *nhd.* butter, *gen.* buttern *m.* vorkommt, auch ein männliches putiro, putirin gesetzt werden. Man spricht noch heute in **Östreich, Baiern, Tirol,** in der **Schweiz**, selbst in der **Pfalz** und in **Franken** der butter, der buttern

Auch im schwäbischen Dialekt ist Butter ein Maskulinum.

Man kann nun spekulieren, dass vielleicht das Geschlecht des ursprünglich für *Butter* verwendeten Wortes übernommen wurde: [der Anke](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GA04109), [das Schmalz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS13082). Dafür habe ich aber keine Belege finden können.

Comment: Man sollte auch bedenken, dass iim schwäbischen Dialekt der weibliche Artikel "d'" ist. Ohne sich die Zunge zu verrenken, passt der eben nicht vor ein "B". Der Schwabe kann also gar nicht so einfach *d` Butter* sagen. Möglicherweise ist ja das ein guter Grund...

Answer (score 23):

Zum Genus von „Butter“ gibt es eine Karte im *[Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache](http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f15a-f/):*

[image: Atlas zur deutschen Alltagssprache]

Answer (score 6):

Also ich arbeite seit 1,5 Jahren 
in einem Kindergarten in Ravensburg und dort gibt es etliche Leute die *der Butter* sagen, aber in Niedersachsen, wo ich bis vor kurzem lebte, habe ich noch nie einen Menschen *der Butter* sagen hören.

Answer (score 3):

"Der" Butter entstand oft verwendet in Zusammenhang mit dem alemannischen Wort für Butter "Anken" (noch heute in der Schweiz üblich). Der (Butter-)Anken ist das Stück Butter, welches früher in eine geschnitzte Holzform (den Buttermodel) gedrückt, somit geformt und danach gekühlt und in Butterpapier eingewickelt wurde.

Comment: »Entstand«? Kannst du das belegen?

Answer (score 1):

In meinem Schwabenland sagt man "die Butter". "Der Butter" sagt auf der Ostalb kein Mensch.
Und wenn man es schwäbisch sagt, dann gibt es kein der oder die, es heißt z.B. "Gib mer mol da Butter" oder "Gib mer mol d'Butter". Hin und wieder gefolgt von einem "..., bitte".

Comment: Natürlich gibt es im Schwäbischen kein *der* oder *die*, aber eine Entsprechung dazu. "Da Butter" ist die schwäbische Entsprechung von "der Butter", die Entsprechung zu "die Butter" wäre "d' Butter". Folglich gibt es (inzwischen) auch auf der Ostalb beide Formen. Wobei ich (der ich nicht aus der Ostalb, sondern aus dem Gäu komme) vermute, dass "da Butter" ursprünglicher ist.

Comment: Meine Verwandten aus Ellwangen (Ostalbkreis) sagen sehr wohl "der Butter".

Answer (score -4):

Badendialekt: Ich hätte gerne von der Butter, der Wurst. Der = dieser.

Comment: Das hat weder was mit Baden zu tun, noch mit dem sächlichen Geschlecht. "Ich hätte gerne von dem Marzipanbrot." - nicht wahr?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17554)

Comment: @Robert I think it's formally a valid answer, even if short and unsourced. That said, this answer is just wrong - deletion is not for wrong answers, downvotes are.