# Fehlerhafte Verwendung des Artikels „der“ für Dativ Plural. Wie klingt es für Muttersprachler?

Tags: grammar, article

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich spiele mit *der* Bällen. ← Hier sollte *den* statt *der* stehen.

---

Der Dativ ist der einzige Fall, in dem Feminin Singular und Plural verschiedene Artikel haben. Daher ist es nicht schwer, diesen zu verwechseln, wenn man die deutsche Grammatik anhand von Tabellen in Sprachbüchern gelernt hat.

```
            Sing. (f) | Plural
Nominativ | die       | die
Genitiv   | der       | der
Dativ     | der       | den
Akkusativ | die       | die
```

Anfangs habe ich diesen Fehler auch mehrmals begangen. Grammatisch ist es, wie ich inzwischen weiß, eindeutig falsch. Aber wie klingt es in den Ohren eines Muttersprachlers?

- Ist es möglich, dass es in einem Dialekt *der* sein kann? Also kann ein deutscher Muttersprachler mit einem bestimmten Dialekt es so sagen? Wenn ja, welchen Dialekt betrifft das?
- Wenn ein Muttersprachler es irgendwo so vorfindet, wie schwerwiegend empfindet er diesen Fehler? Ist es ein schwerwiegender Fehler oder bleibt der Fehler wohlmöglich sogar unerkennt?
- Ist es möglich, dass ein Muttersprachler es so sagt, zum Beispiel weil er sich beeilt und schnell schreibt?

**Ergänzung:** @Em1 hat die Frage signifikant verändert, und ich habe auch mit einem Beispiel ergänzt. Vor dem VtC bitte nochmal prüfen, ob diese Frage noch immer geschlossen werden soll.

Comment: Meine Kinder pflegen bisweilen so zu reden. Aber nicht, ohne sich dabei hab totzulachen. Scheint ihnen also aufzufallen.

Comment: @tofro Danke! Dann scheint es in der alltaglichen Sprache einem größeren Fehler?

Comment: @peterh Genau das wollte ich damit sagen. Freundliche Erwachsene werden dich dafür nicht auslachen, weil sie wissen, dass die deutsche Sprache nicht leicht ist, aber "Kinder und Narren sagen die Wahrheit"

Comment: Vielleicht von Interesse: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/do-unschooled-people-use-cases-correctly-e-g-in-germany-and-in-russia

Comment: Um die erste Frage kurz aus meiner _Sicht_ zu beantworten: Einen falschen Artikel aus dem Mund eines _Nicht-Muttersprachlers_ zu hören fällt zwar auf, ist aber nicht sehr ungewöhnlich. IMHO klingt _öfters_ aus dem Mund eines Akademikers hingegen wie lange Fingernägel auf einer Schultafel...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Für den Lernenden bereiten die Fälle ein Problem, deshalb [denken manche von ihnen](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/9752/do-unschooled-people-use-cases-correctly-e-g-in-germany-and-in-russia), dass sie auch für Muttersprachler eher unwichtig sind. Das ist nicht so. Sicher gibt es einige Fälle, in denen Umgangssprache oder Dialekt andere Fälle verwenden als die Schriftsprache (zum Beispiel, wenn es um den Genitiv geht), aber im Allgemeinen ist der Gebrauch der Fälle für den Muttersprachler völlig natürlich. Wie Du schon aus der Tabelle siehst, höre ich, wenn Du *der Katzen* sagst, einen Genitiv, und wenn an der Stelle ein Dativ sein sollte, stolpere ich darüber.

Andererseits werde ich immer noch verstehen, was Du meinst. Und beispielsweise machen alle ausländischen Journalisten im [Internationalen Frühschoppen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Internationale_Fr%C3%BChschoppen) grammatische Fehler, die dem Hörer auffallen, und sie erscheinen trotzdem nicht ungebildet. Du solltest Dich also um richtige Grammatik bemühen, Dich aber nicht genieren, wenn Du Fehler machst.

Answer (score 7):

Auch wenn viele andere Sprachen darauf verzichten (und es deswegen für Muttersprachler dieser Sprachen verständlicherweise schwer nachvollziehbar ist), ist der Artikel in richtigem Genus, Kasus, Numerus ein unverzichtbarer Teil der deutschen Sprache.

Der richtige Artikel ist ein derart wichtiger Informationsträger im Deutschen, dass es kaum einen Muttersprachler geben dürfte, der (zumindest bei gängiger Wortwahl, ich nehme mal falsche Artikel für Fremdwörter und extrem selten benutzte Wörter aus) einen falsch deklinierten Artikel verwenden würde, oder auch nur aus Flüchtigkeit falsch verwenden würde.

Ich habe in meinem Kommentar oben mit Absicht das Beispiel „meine Kinder lachen darüber“ genannt, weil das wohl ein untrügliches Zeichen dafür ist, *wie falsch* ein falscher Artikel aufgefasst werden kann. Das Verständnis und die Höflichkeit Erwachsener verdecken hier viel, man braucht sich als Nicht-Muttersprachler aber auch nicht wirklich für einen falschen Artikel zu schämen.

Es gibt im Deutschen einige Substantive, die in Dialekten mit von der Hochsprache abweichendem Geschlecht verwendet werden. (z. B. „Teller“ (Hochsprache: m / süddeutsche Dialekte: n), „Butter“ (Hochsprache: f / süddeutsche Dialekte: m). Trotzdem würde man auch bei abweichendem Genus annehmen, dass die Deklination folgerichtig gebildet wird, solange es den Fall auch im Dialekt gibt (Schwäbisch z. B. ohne Genitiv)

EDIT:
Das Deutsche verwendet den Artikel, um den Zuhörenden „darauf vorzubereiten, was jetzt kommt“. Damit stellt es beim Hörer Weichen, die, sobald etwas Unerwartetes (etwa ein Substantiv, das nicht zum verwendeten Artikel passt) ankommt, wieder zurückgestellt werden müssen. Das stört das Verständnis in etwa so, wie wenn man im Englischen falsche Präpositionen verwenden oder vom strengen SPO abweichen würde (das Englische transportiert vieles von dem, wozu das Deutsche Fälle und Artikel benutzt, über standardisierte Wortreihenfolge und Präpositionen).

Comment: Es gibt imho einen Grund, warum man schonmal den falschen Artikel verwenden mag, und das ist, wenn man sich — während man spricht — für ein anderes Wort entscheidet, als man ursprünglich sagen wollte. Dieser Fehler wird aber selbstverständlich selbst bemerkt und häufig witzelt derjenige, der sich versprochen hat, sofort selber darüber.

Comment: Ja - das passt zu meiner Bemerkung "Weichen werden gestellt" - Wenn der Sprecher noch nicht weiss, wohin er fahren will oder es sich unterwegs anders überlegt, kann er die Weichen u.U. natürlich auch falsch stellen.

Comment: Bezüglich der Behauptung, dass "das Butter" korrekt ist: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/der-die-das-butter

Comment: @Dodekeract Bitte nochmal (richtig) lesen: Süddeutsche Dialekte sagen "**der** Butter", nicht "**das** Butter". Und das steht da oben auch.

Comment: @tofro Ich wollte nicht implizieren, dass der oder das richtig ist. Meiner Meinung (und laut Duden & Link) nach heißt es die Butter.

Comment: *Das* ist sowohl in Hochsprache als auch im Dialekt falsch.

Comment: @tofro Was genau mein Punkt ist. In dieser Antwort steht dass es das oder der Butter sein müsste, obwohl es die heißt.

Comment: @Dodekeract Oh, danke (klick). Ein Versehen, korrigiert.

Answer (score 6):

> Ich spiele mit der Bällen.

Wenn ich diesen Satz hören würde, und wüsste, dass mein Gegenüber Deutsch kann, würde ich mich fragen, wer denn diese *Bällen* ist, ob es ein Mädel oder ein Haustier ist. *Mit* ist so fest mit dem Dativ verankert, dass mein Sprachzentrum beim Auftauchen von *mit der* automatisch auf Feminin Singular geschaltet hat.

Nun ist *die Bällen* im Singular kein mir bekanntes Wort, deswegen hat mein Gehirn automatisch die Rückfallebene *unbekannter Name* aufgemacht. Es stellt sich die Frage, *wessen* Name das ist und ob ich ihn wirklich richtig verstanden habe.

Answer (score 2):

Grundsätzlich wage ich zu behaupten, dass Muttersprachler 99% Prozent der Artikelfehler sofort erkennen und es ihnen auffällt. Die größte Ausnahme dürften dabei Wörter bilden, die - aufgrund von Dialekten - häufig dem falschen Genus zugeordnet werden.

So ist im Rheinischen beispielsweise "der Kabel" sehr geläufig, obwohl "das Kabel" richtig wäre. In solchen Fällen kann es also durchaus vorkommen, dass ein Muttersprachler den Fehler nicht entdeckt. Dein konkretes Beispiel mit dem Dativ sollte allerdings *jedem* auffallen.

Außerdem werden solche Artikelfehler auch nicht gemacht, weil ein Muttersprachler "schnell schreibt". Der einzige Fall - bei Artikeln - wo ich das kenne, ist mit unbestimmten Artikel. Das heißt, dass man statt "eine Gans" in der Eile "ein Gans" als Tippfehler schreibt, aber eher geläufig als umgangssprachliche Kurzform wäre "ne Gans", was wiederum theoretisch richtig wäre.

Answer (score 1):

Mir würde dieser Fehler sofort auffallen und er würde mich verwirren, weil es nicht richtig ist.

Es gibt aber tatsächlich Ausnahmen, was die Artikel im bayrischen Dialekt betrifft. So sagt man in **manchen Regionen** in Bayern beispielsweise *das* Teller oder *der* Butter, obwohl *der* Teller und *die* Butter richtig wären.
Das sind aber regionale Ausnahmen, an die ich mich beim Deutsch lernen nicht halten würde.