# Etymologie der Wortbildung mit -er

Tags: etymology, morphology

[1]

Substantive, die sich aus Verben ableiten, indem die Endung *-er* an den Stamm des Verbs angefügt sind, haben maskulines Genus:

- *lehren* → *der Lehrer*
- *streuen* → *der Salzstreuer*
- *dreschen* → *der Mähdrescher*

[2]

Außerdem gibt es maskuline Worte auf *-er*,  bei denen nicht klar ist, auf welches Verb sie zurückgehen, oder ob sie überhaupt auf ein Verb zurückgehen:

- *der Priester* (nicht etwa von **priesten*, sondern von gr. πρεσβύτερος (presbýteros), [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Priester#et-1))
- *der Zucker*  (nicht etwa von *zucken*, sondern von arab. *sukkar*, [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zucker#et-1))

[3]

Es gibt aber auch feminine Wort, die auf *-er* enden

- *der / die Butter* (bemerkenswerterweise existiert in Dialekten auch die maskuline Form)
- *die Mutter* (wie bei allen Verwandtschaftsbezeichnungen folgt das Genus hier dem Sexus)
- *die Schwester* (ebenso)

Ich interessiere mich für die Sprachgeschichte dieser Wortbildung [1]:

1. Wann ist diese Wortbildung im Deutschen bzw. in Vorgängersprachen entstanden?
2. Falls sie aus anderen Sprachen ins Deutsche übernommen wurde, woher stammt sie?
3. Lässt sich nachvollziehen, warum die Formen maskulin sind?
4. Ist das Genus der anderen Substantive unter [2] aus einer Analogie entstanden?
5. Habe ich unter [3] noch andere Beispiele übersehen?

Zu 2. fällt mir nur assoziativ ein, dass es eine analoge Konstruktion im Lateinischen mit der Endung *-tor* gibt:

- *orare* → *orator*
- *movere* → *motor*
- *rotare* → *rotor*
- *quaerere* → *quaestor*

Schon über die Beantwortung einzelner Fragen oder auch nur Hinweise zu einzelnen Fragen wäre ich dankbar.

Comment: "Der Butter" existiert in süddeutschen Dialekten durch den französischen Einfluss (le beurre). Zu deiner eigentlichen Frage hab ich leider keine wertvolle Antwort.

Comment: Es gibt auch viele sächliche Substantive, die auf -er enden: das Wasser, das Opfer, das Alter, das Wetter, das Gewitter, das Theater, das Lager, das Orchester, das Fenster, das Wunder, das Kloster, das Center, das Ufer, das Silber ... Männlich und sächlich: der/das Meter, der/das Liter. Auch sächlich, passt aber nicht ganz zu den anderen weil das Wort einsilbig ist und die Endung -er daher nicht zu einer Reduktionssilbe gehört: das Meer.

Comment: Meine Vermutung ist:
Im Türkischen beudeutet "er" Mann, männlich, Soldat. Es könnte doch sein, dass das Deutsche "-er" aus dem Türkischen entlehnt hat, um Maskulinum zu bilden:)))
Denkbar ist es...

Comment: @Korhan: Nein, das ist nicht denkbar.

Comment: Es mag sich lohnen, in andere moderne europäische Sprachen mit möglicherweise geringerem romanischen Einfluß zu schauen: z.B. Ritter (dt.), Riddare (schwed.), Ridder (norweg., dän.),....

Comment: @tofro: Inwiefern?

Comment: @userunknown Ist das nicht offensichtlich? Gemeinsamkeiten solcher Wortbildungsphänomene zwischen germanischen Sprachen lassen auf eine sehr frühe Entstehung dieser Suffixe schliessen.

Comment: Nein, war es nicht, da ich weder Schwedisch, Norwegisch noch Dänisch kann und den Stamm der Wörter in diesen Sprachen nicht kenne, nicht die Prävalenz, nicht typische Endungen usw. und auch nicht weiß, welche Sprache auf welche Vorform zurückgeht und wo sich welche Lautverschiebungen ereignet haben. Wieso schaust Du dann nicht in die Sprachen, um uns die Schlussfolgerungen zu präsentieren?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nhd. *-er* hat verschiedene Quellen, die bis auf die ahd. Zeit oder weiter zurückreichen.

- Lehnwörter: *Kaiser* (ahd. *keisur*) von lat. *caesar*, *Butter* (mhd. *buter*) von gr.-lat. *butyrum*
- Lehnsuffix lat. *-ārius*: *Müller* (ahd. *mullinari*), *Schüler* (ahd. *skuolāri*). Immer maskulin*, ursprünglich um Ableitungen von Nomen zu bilden (Wilmanns, S. 284 f.).
- germ. *r*-Stämme: Verwandtschaftsbezeichnungen *Vater, Bruder; Mutter, Tochter, Schwester*. Genus nach dem Sexus.
- germ. Suffix *-r*: *Acker* (ahd. *ackar*), *Finger* (ahd. *fingar*) mask.; *Jahr* (ahd. *jār*), *Feuer* (ahd. *fiur*) neut.; *Schnur* (ahd. *snuor*), *Feder* (ahd. *fëdara)* fem.
- ungeklärt: *Kater, Ganser, Tauber* (mask. Bezeichnungen für männliche Tiere)

Die Beispiele habe ich aus: Wilmanns, *Deutsche Grammatik*, 2. Abteilung: *Wortbildung*, S. 275-296. [Link](https://archive.org/details/deutschegrammat02wilm/page/274).

Intuitiv scheint klar, daß das lat. Lehnsuffix *-ārius* die Quelle für das produktive nhd. Suffix *-er* der maskulinen Berufs- oder Tätigkeitsbezeichnungen (Nomina agentis) sowie der Nomina instrumenti (*Zähler*, *Zeiger*) ist. Das Genus der Lehnwörter unterliegt, wie zu erwarten, Schwankungen. Bei den alten germanischen Ableitungen auf *-r* waren alle Genera vertreten, aber die Maskulina waren die größte Gruppe und sind im Lauf der Zeit durch Übertritte angewachsen (Beispiele bei Wilmanns auf S. 283).

Ein paar Feminina auf *-er*: *Ader, Faser, Feder, Feier, Kammer, Klammer, Lauer, Leber, Leier, Marter, Mauer, Natter, Schleuder, Schulter, Ziffer*.

*<sub>Sie sind im Ahd. auch dann maskulin, wenn sie von einem lat. Neutrum stammen und eine Sache bezeichnen, z.B. ahd. *kellari* von lat. *cellarium* (Wilmanns, S. 292). Das hatte ich zunächst nicht richtig gesehen.</sub>

Comment: "weiter zurück" https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-r%CC%A5 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-wr%CC%A5 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/p%C3%A9h%E2%82%82wr%CC%A5 https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/weh%E2%82%81ros https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/sw%C3%A9s%C5%8Dr https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-t%E1%B8%97r https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-teros etc. nicht gesichert ...

Answer (score 0):

Ein paar weitere wichtige Beispiele, die nicht hochdeutsch sind

- altnordische Nominativ-Endung *-r* aus **-az* entsprechend lateinisch *-us*, vgl. *Tyr*, en. *tuesday*, lat. *Deus*, althochdeutsch *Ziu*

In Runenschrift wurde zwar noch unterschieden zwischen ererbtem *r* und Rotazismus, aber der Ausgang ist derselbe vgl. *war*, en. *was*; *wer*, *wessen*; regional aber auch *wo* wie engl. *who*, gotisch  (ƕas),  (ƕa),  (ƕē).

Da auslautendes *r* nunmehr vokalisch realisiert bzw. "verschluckt" wird, ist von weitreichender Hyperkorrektur auszugehen, vgl. lat. *mater* (> *Materie*, *Matrix*), de. *Masse* ("mineralisches, halbflüssiges Bindemittel für Steine", en. *brick and mortar*, wie *Mulch* zu *Mulde*, *missa*), denn μᾶζα (mâza, “bread”) > *massa* > *Masse* ("Menge") bzw. *missa* (Putz wird "geschmissen") sind Zufall.

Demnach ist *Mutter* als a-Stamm zu betrachten. Einen großen Unterschied macht das nicht für die Beugung, s. nur "Futtern wie bei Muttern". In einigen Fällen könnte man Dativ unterstellen, so *Wasser*, vgl. Sanskrit *var* (versteh ich nicht), vielleicht *Kater* zu *Schmits Katze* also der hinterm Ofen vgl. italienisch *getto* "Schmiede", *gatto*, venetisch *gato* "Katze" (Herkunft letztendlich ungewiss), oder einfach sowas wie *Spiel(er)gemeinschaft*, was doppeldeutig Plural/Dativ zu sein scheint, im Fall von *Sonnenschein* aber kaum Zweifel lässt, vgl. en. *soar*, lat. *aura* (wat?).

Dagegen weist bspw. **ahaz* > *Ähre* Epenthese auf, vgl. en. *ear (of corn)*, vermutlich weil sonst nur *äh* übrig bliebe, anders wiederum *Ohren*, en. *ears*, jedenfalls rhotisch. Wegen *Lauscher* oder sogar *Löffel (vom Hasen)* ist davon ausgehend Lamdazismus im Verb ausgehend nicht unwahrscheinlich, trotzdem diese bis auf die Proto-Indo-Europäische Rekonstruktion zu unterscheiden sind. In diesen Maßstäben ist "altnordisch" offenbar nur bedingt sinnvoll

- gemeintürkische (!) Plural-Endung *-ler-*; laut en.Wiktionary hat Avar, eine nomadische Mischsprache, Spuren im Deutschen hinterlassen (s. "Pfad"), archeologisch kaum von Gothen und anderen Konsorten zu trennen.

Demnach müsste *scholari* bzw. gr. σκολε (Herkunft unbekannt) bspw. zu türkisch *kü* zählen, das selbst aus einem indo-europäischen Idiom entlehnt ist und oben zu *lauschen* gezählt wird. Ein daran anschließendes Problem ist die Redundanz der Wurzeln zu *lesen* bzw. lat. *lego*, *lexicon*, ita. *lessico* und demgegenüber *erklären*, das nicht mit *clarus* sondern ebenfalls mit Rotazismus zu denselben zu vergleichen wäre, ferner *Klerus*; macht aber keiner. Man sägt sich ja nicht den Ast ab, auf dem man sitzt.

- K-Aorist, palatal, völlig unklar.

Vorgermanisch *k wird *affriziiert* (?) und neigt teils zum rhotischen. Vgl. Ru. *-ek*, *-ik*, etwa *Gopnik*, *Köpenick*, *Sputnik*, etc.

- Ägyptisches Aleph wird zwar in Umschrift als *a* wiedergegeben, dürfte aber ursprünglich rhotisch gewesen sein.

Weil pronomial erste person singular, klitisch

Answer (score 0):

'Der Butter' habe ich in Kärnten gehört. Ich nehme an, dass Italienisch die Leute beeinflusste. Wir sagen nämlich 'il burro'. Das ist männlich.

Comment: Ja, im Schwäbischen gibt es "der Butter" auch, und auch im Französchen ist es "le beurre". Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8259/der-die-das-butter